# Radiobutton selection in new window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am making a movie recommendation GUI using tkinter. When the user selects a radio button I want it to open in a new window with the selection inside of it. So if someone chooses comedy I can code in different movies and have them pop up randomly in a new window. I have the command in place to open the window but I am having trouble calling back the selected choice.

```
from tkinter import *

class movie1:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("Movie Recommendation")

    self.label = Label(master, text= "Welcome to the movie recommendation application! \n Please select the genre of the movie you would like to see.")
    self.label.pack(padx=25, pady=25)

    CheckVar1 = StringVar()

    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Action", variable=CheckVar1, value=1, command=self.reco)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Comedy", variable=CheckVar1, value=2, command=self.reco)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Documentary", variable=CheckVar1, value=3, command=self.reco)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Horror", variable=CheckVar1, value=4, command=self.reco)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Romance", variable=CheckVar1, value=5, command=self.reco)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.radiobutton.cget("value")


def reco(self):
    self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
    if ("value") == 1:
        print("1")


root = Tk()
my_gui = movie1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: An example on getting which Radiobutton was checked http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you.

First: Change the line 11 to: `self.CheckVar1 = IntVar()` since your answers values in `radiobutton` are integers, not strings. In addition, we add `self.` to the `CheckVar1` variable because we want access it later in the `reco` method.

Second: Change the line 33 to: `if self.CheckVar1.get() == 1:`. Here we used the `.get()` method associated to the variable `self.CheckVar1` in order to get the value stored in it.

Now, if you run the script, you will get the `"1"` printed (in the IDLE) when you select the `Action` option.